# How to add more than one background image in JavaFx

Tags: java, css, background-image

I can add a background image to a node in JavaFx via css like so:

```
.backgroundImage {
    -fx-background-image: url("../Image.png");
    -fx-background-size: 100 100;
    -fx-background-position: 0 0;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Is there a way I can add more than one background image to one node? Any way will do, even if not in css.

Comment: Would each background image overlap the other 100%? Or only a bit? And why would you want to do it? What's the result you want? Maybe there's another solution :)

Comment: @Rvervuurt - Say we have them overlap a bit so that they are all at least partially visible.

Comment: Why won't you work with different `div`s that will cover the page with 100% `width` and `height` and stack them in the way you want? I'll try and set up a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked:

```
.backgroundImages {
    -fx-background-image: url("../Image1.png"),  url("../Image2.png");
    -fx-background-size: 246 1, 6 11;
    -fx-background-position: 0 0, 4 center;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```